# Why is topdir set to its default value when rpmbuild called from tcl?

Tags: tcl, rpm

I have a tcl script which 'exec' rpmbuild. When doing so, the 'topdir' used by rpmbuild is wrong. I have a .rpmmacros file in my home directory and if I call manually rpmbuild, it works fine, ie. the 'topdir' is not the default one.

I added a *[exec rpmbuild "--showrc" ]* in the tcl script to check the value of *topdir* and it says '-14: _topdir    %{_usrsrc}/redhat' which is the default value.

Can someone explain me why is that situation and how to solve it ?

I would prefer not to have to specify it with --define because it is actually done in a makefile and I don't want to touch it (if no other choice, I will do it).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

There's two ways to change the default rpmbuild topdir:

1. Per-User: By configuring the RPM topdir in $HOME/.rpmmacros

   ```
   %_topdir    %{getenv:HOME}/rpmbuild
   ```
2. Per-Project: By configuring the RPM topdir in the Makefile or on the command line

   ```
   rpmbuild --define '_topdir build' -ba package.spec
   ```

Note: in both cases, you will need to make sure your topdir directory has the appropriate directories (BUILD, SRPM, RPM, SPECS and SOURCES)

Comment: awesome.  "--define '_topdir xxxxx'" is the most underdocumented piece of rpm lore.  I've been searching for this for ages.

Comment: Mad kudos for dredging this up. Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Just placing `$HOME` doesn't work - you should use `%{getenv:HOME}`

Comment: I had issues using a relative path; I think it's best to always have this be an abs directory (eg: topdir=`pwd`/../foo)

Comment: how about define a macro in the SPEC file? like： %define _topdir  path/of/new/topdir

Comment: This inspired me to try a per-source-package `_topdir`: `%_topdir %{getenv:HOME}/rpmbuild/%{name}/` - and it works! the mixing of files bothered me all the time when working on more than one package, now i have them separate.

Answer (score 10):

In **RHEL6** do:

```
  rpm --showrc|grep topdir
  rpm --showrc|grep srcrpmdir
```

To see what are the paths being used !

Make this change (my topdir was NOT set to `/usr/src/`):

```
vi  /usr/lib/rpm/macros
#       Path to top of build area.
#%_topdir               %{getenv:HOME}/rpmbuild
%_topdir                %{_usrsrc}/redhat

rpm --showrc|grep topdir    now shows   /usr/src/redhat/ as its BUILD dir
```

Answer (score 1):

TCL will exec in the current directory by default. You can change the current directory by using the TCL command http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/cd.htm cd, for example:

```
cd ~username
```

If topdir is an environment variable, you might be able to set it http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/tclvars.htm#M4 like this:

```
set env(topdir) whatever/you/want
```

Answer (score 1):

My first check would be to make sure you execute the same thing.
Do these two on the command line to make sure aliases or paths
do not disturb anything.

```
which rpmbuild

echo 'puts [auto_execok rpmbuild]' | tclsh
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this is due to the variable $HOME which is not set when rpmbuild is called.
The variable is used to search the '/rpmmacros' file. I suggest to use the command 'printenv' to verify.