# Getting SOURCES from dynamic subdirectories

Tags: linux, rpm, rhel, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I need to build multiple RPM packages. But it's getting a missing file as it is searching in the `/SOURCES/` directory instead of searching in the respective subdirectory.
Is there any way to solve it without touching the `spec` files, with rpm `macros`?

After executing `rpmbuild -bb ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/*.spec` getting the following error:

```
error: File /home/centos/rpmbuild/SOURCES/autoconf-2.69.tar.gz: No such file or directory
```

Here is my `~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/` tree after symlinking with the development codes:

```
~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
├── autoconf -> /home/centos/Project/autoconf/
│   ├── autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
│   ├── autoconf.spec
│   └── config.site
├── autorespond-toaster -> /home/centos/Project/autorespond-toaster/
│   ├── autorespond-2.0.5.tar.bz2
│   ├── autorespond-toaster.spec
│   └── autorespond_utf-8.patch
├── bind -> /home/centos/Project/bind/
│   ├── bind-9.3.1rc1-sdb_tools-Makefile.in
│   ├── bind-9.9.9-P6.tar.gz
│   ├── bind.spec
│   ├── config-8.tar.bz2
│   ├── Copyright.caching-nameserver
│   ├── dnszone.schema
│   ├── flexible.m4
│   ├── ldap2zone.c
│   ├── named.conf.sample
│   ├── named.init
│   ├── named.init.el4
│   ├── named.logrotate
│   ├── named.NetworkManager
│   ├── named.portreserve
│   ├── named.sysconfig
│   ├── README.sdb_pgsql
│   └── rfc1912.txt
```

And `~/rpmbuild/SPECS/` tree:

```
~/rpmbuild/SPECS/
├── autoconf.spec -> /home/centos/Project/autoconf/autoconf.spec
├── autorespond-toaster.spec -> /home/centos/Project/autorespond-toaster/autorespond-toaster.spec
├── bind.spec -> /home/centos/Project/bind/bind.spec
```

## REPOs

- https://github.com/KloxoNGCommunity/autoconf
- https://github.com/KloxoNGCommunity/autorespond-toaster
- https://github.com/KloxoNGCommunity/bind

Comment: All you're showing is symlinks; we need to see what the `Sources` line(s) say in the specfiles.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco I have updated the post with repositories. please check.

Comment: If you override `_topdir`, you can use project-specific directories, such as `autoconf/SPECS`, `autoconf/SOURCES`, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416983/why-is-topdir-set-to-its-default-value-when-rpmbuild-called-from-tcl

Comment: I am asking for the `Sources` line(s) in the specfiles, not repositories.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco 

- https://github.com/KloxoNGCommunity/autoconf/blob/dev/autoconf.spec
- https://github.com/KloxoNGCommunity/autorespond-toaster/blob/dev/autorespond-toaster.spec
- https://github.com/KloxoNGCommunity/bind/blob/dev/bind.spec

Comment: @omajid How to make _topdir dynamic to subdirectories?

Comment: @omajid Not `autoconf/SOURCES` but `SOURCES/autoconf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should redefine the `_sourcedir` macro this way:

```
rpmbuild --define "_sourcedir /home/centos/Project/autoconf" \
    -bb /home/centos/Project/autoconf/autoconf.spec
```

So this script should do the complete job:

```
for pkg in autoconf autorespond-toaster bind; do
    rpmbuild --define "_sourcedir /home/centos/Project/$pkg" \
        -bb /home/centos/Project/$pkg/${pkg}.spec
done
```